# PrestaShop Crossselling Products order by sales [PHP MOD]

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to modify the PrestaShop module Crosselling, I need to add 2 mods:

- Hide out of stock items from the list.
- Order the product list by times that the product has shared order with the page product.

I have located the product list function:

```
if (count($orders) > 0) {
        $list = '';
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $list .= (int)$order['id_order'].',';
        }
        $list = rtrim($list, ',');

        $list_product_ids = join(',', $products_id);

        if (Group::isFeatureActive()) {
            $sql_groups_join = '
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_product` cp ON (cp.`id_category` = product_shop.id_category_default
                AND cp.id_product = product_shop.id_product)
            LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_group` cg ON (cp.`id_category` = cg.`id_category`)';
            $groups = FrontController::getCurrentCustomerGroups();
            $sql_groups_where = 'AND cg.`id_group` '.(count($groups) ? 'IN ('.implode(',', $groups).')' : '='.(int)Group::getCurrent()->id);
        }

        $order_products = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
            SELECT DISTINCT od.product_id, pl.name, pl.description_short, pl.link_rewrite, p.reference, i.id_image, product_shop.show_price,
                cl.link_rewrite category, p.ean13, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p ON (p.id_product = od.product_id)
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').
            (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
            ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
            '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $this->context->shop) :  Product::sqlStock('p', 'product', false,
                $this->context->shop)).'
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = od.product_id'.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang cl ON (cl.id_category = product_shop.id_category_default'
                .Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'image i ON (i.id_product = od.product_id)
            '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? $sql_groups_join : '').'
            WHERE od.id_order IN ('.$list.')
            AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.'
            AND cl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.'
            AND od.product_id NOT IN ('.$list_product_ids.')
            AND i.cover = 1
            AND stock.quantity > 1
            AND product_shop.active = 1
            '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? $sql_groups_where : '').'
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT '.(int)Configuration::get('CROSSSELLING_NBR'));

        $tax_calc = Product::getTaxCalculationMethod();

        foreach ($order_products as &$order_product) {
            $order_product['id_product'] = (int)$order_product['product_id'];
            $order_product['image'] = $this->context->link->getImageLink($order_product['link_rewrite'],
                (int)$order_product['product_id'].'-'.(int)$order_product['id_image'], ImageType::getFormatedName('home'));
            $order_product['link'] = $this->context->link->getProductLink((int)$order_product['product_id'], $order_product['link_rewrite'],
                $order_product['category'], $order_product['ean13']);
            if (Configuration::get('CROSSSELLING_DISPLAY_PRICE') && ($tax_calc == 0 || $tax_calc == 2)) {
                $order_product['displayed_price'] = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$order_product['product_id'], true, null);
            } elseif (Configuration::get('CROSSSELLING_DISPLAY_PRICE') && $tax_calc == 1) {
                $order_product['displayed_price'] = Product::getPriceStatic((int)$order_product['product_id'], false, null);
            }
            $order_product['allow_oosp'] = Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock((int)$order_product['out_of_stock']);

            if (!isset($final_products_list[$order_product['product_id'].'-'.$order_product['id_image']])) {
                $final_products_list[$order_product['product_id'].'-'.$order_product['id_image']] = $order_product;
            }
        }
    }

    return $final_products_list;
}
```

So, to hide the out of stock items I have added: **" AND stock.quantity > 1 "** and seems that works fine, but I am not sure how to mod "ORDER BY RAND()" to order the products by the value of (count($orders)

Maybe I am misunderstanding the function work, my PHP skills are limited.

thanks for your help

First try:

```
 $order_products = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS('
            SELECT od.product_id, pl.name, pl.description_short, pl.link_rewrite, p.reference, i.id_image, product_shop.show_price,
                cl.link_rewrite category, p.ean13, stock.out_of_stock, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity
            FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'order_detail od
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product p ON (p.id_product = od.product_id)
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product', 'p').
            (Combination::isFeatureActive() ? 'LEFT JOIN `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product_attribute` pa
            ON (p.`id_product` = pa.`id_product`)
            '.Shop::addSqlAssociation('product_attribute', 'pa', false, 'product_attribute_shop.`default_on` = 1').'
            '.Product::sqlStock('p', 'product_attribute_shop', false, $this->context->shop) :  Product::sqlStock('p', 'product', false,
                $this->context->shop)).'
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'product_lang pl ON (pl.id_product = od.product_id'.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl').')
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang cl ON (cl.id_category = product_shop.id_category_default'
                .Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl').')
            LEFT JOIN '._DB_PREFIX_.'image i ON (i.id_product = od.product_id)
            '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? $sql_groups_join : '').'
            WHERE od.id_order IN ('.$list.')
            GROUP BY od.product_id
            AND pl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.'
            AND cl.id_lang = '.(int)$this->context->language->id.'
            AND od.product_id NOT IN ('.$list_product_ids.')
            AND i.cover = 1
            AND product_shop.active = 1
            AND stock.quantity > 0
            '.(Group::isFeatureActive() ? $sql_groups_where : '').'
            ORDER BY sum(od.quantity) DESC
            LIMIT '.(int)Configuration::get('CROSSSELLING_NBR'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The original query is already joining the **ps_order_detail** table,
so it will be easier for you to order by "ordered product quantities".

You'll need to remove DISTINCT from select, group by **od.product_id** and order by **sum(od.quantity) desc** - This can make the query a little heavier ,though.

Comment: Thanks for tour reply, I have try to edit my code with your indications but its not working. I have edited the first mensaje with your code.